# How can I use Hex codes when specifiying a color for defaultFillColor?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am just getting started with learning scripting for CC software.
I have been reading the documentation and have managed to change the fill colour with:

```
var colfil      = new RGBColor();
colfil.red      = 100;
colfil.green    = 255;
colfil.blue     = 100;
app.activeDocument.defaultFillColor = colfil
```

While this is really cool and all. How can I just pass the hex code equivalent of the above:

```
app.activeDocument.defaultFillColor = "64FF64"
```

I am relying on another tool to provide me with a colour and it only outputs a hex code, I simply want to pass this Hex colour to illustrator.

I am really not advanced at all, so please pardon me if the obvious eludes me. Is there a way to use Hex codes here?

Comment: Would `app.activeDocument.defaultFillColor = "#64FF64"` work? I'm not familiar with adobe illustrator or extendscript, but that's how it works on many languages. The difference here being the "#" at the start of the hex code.

Comment: @ethry hey thanks for that I just tried it, it throws an error, saying it expects an object at line 5.

Comment: I don't think it's possible then. You could convert the hex code to RGB and do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function get_rgb_color(hex) {
  var color   = new RGBColor();
  color.red   = parseInt(hex.slice(0,2),16);
  color.green = parseInt(hex.slice(2,4),16);
  color.blue  = parseInt(hex.slice(4,6),16);
  return color;
}

app.activeDocument.defaultFillColor = get_rgb_color("64FF64");
```

Comment: So that is how its done, very enlightning. Thank you.